# How or when to decide to use Invite Keys

Tags: user-feedback

Can't seem to find much on this topic, and I'm not sure if this is the right SE site to ask but here goes:

I'm developing an application/tool that I want to be really easy to use but also very powerful. Rather than open it up to the world for feedback which may or may not give me good data (or too much data for me to use), I've been considering the idea of giving out invite keys to select people in the industry to review the website and give constructive feedback.

Of course, I don't want to run into the Silicon Valley tv show problem of giving this to techs who are savvy enough to figure something out and normal people are left confused; I want REAL people to understand how to use the site too. I do have some UX friends I can invite as well.

What are your thoughts on invite keys? Are there situations where they work well? Don't work well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, This is something that has been done over and over in the industry.

The best example I can come up with is of Dribbble.com

They are still running on pretty much the same model, however, they have turned that into a niche for design domain. If you think that your product is something that a few users will use it passionately, then It's always a good time to use invite systems.

The second example I'd add it is of Uber. Uber is using invites as a guerrilla marketing tool in some certain countries. Users can accumulate points via inviting more people, It's just reverse of how dribbble is using it.

If you're planning to do it just for the beta phase of the product and then open it for everyone. There are many ways to achieve that. I think to get the best results, you should provide your selected users with more invite over a course of time, thus making sure that your product gets a new set of eyeballs every now and then. Also, make sure to incorporate a proper feedback mechanism. You need to talk to all your users frequently and collect whatever feedback they have. unlike silicon valley where things just happen over an unplanned meeting :D

Sticking to just UX practices, I don't think there is anything wrong with using invite approach. Even if there was, This part is all about using the best approach for your product, no matter what rules says.

Comment: Yeah the end goal is to open it up to everyone. Thanks for the tip on providing feedback in-app, too.